# C# Interface Method calls from a controller

Tags: c#, class, model-view-controller, interface

I was just working on some application architecture and this may sound like a stupid question but please explain to me how the following works:

Interface:

```
public interface IMatterDAL
{
    IEnumerable<Matter> GetMattersByCode(string input);
    IEnumerable<Matter> GetMattersBySearch(string input);
}
```

Class:

```
 public class MatterDAL : IMatterDAL
{
    private readonly Database _db;

    public MatterDAL(Database db)
    {
        _db = db;
        LoadAll(); //Private Method
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Matter> GetMattersBySearch(string input)
    {
        //CODE
        return result;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Matter> GetMattersByCode(string input)
    {
       //CODE
        return results;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class MatterController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMatterDAL _publishedData;

    public MatterController(IMatterDAL publishedData)
    {
        _publishedData = publishedData;
    }

    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public JsonResult SearchByCode(string id)
    {
        var searchText = id; //better name for this
        var results = _publishedData.GetMattersBySearch(searchText).Select(
            matter =>
            new
                {
                    MatterCode = matter.Code,
                    MatterName = matter.Name, 
                    matter.ClientCode, 
                    matter.ClientName
                });
        return Json(results);
    }
```

This works, when I call my controller method from jquery and step into it, the call to the _publishedData method, goes into the class MatterDAL.

I want to know how does my controller know to go to the MatterDAL implementation of the Interface IMatterDAL. What if I have another class called MatterDAL2 which is based on the interface. How will my controller know then to call the right method?

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, this is baffling me.

EDIT:

Based on the responses, it seems like this is where the dependency is being resolved:

This is a ninject call:

```
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ICpdMatterDAL>().To<CachedCpdData>();
    }
```

Where CachedCpdData is:

```
public class CachedCpdData : ICpdMatterDAL
{
    private static readonly object CacheLockObject = new object();

    private readonly MatterDAL _matterData;

    public CachedCpdData()
    {
        _matterData = DomainModel.DataAccessManager.Instance.Matters;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Matter> GetMattersForAutoCompleteByCode(string input)
    {
        var cacheKey = string.Format("matter-search-{0}", input ?? "");
        var result = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] as IEnumerable<Matter>;
        if (result == null)
        {
            lock (CacheLockObject)
            {
                result = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] as IEnumerable<Matter>;
                if (result == null)
                {
                    result = _matterData.GetMattersForAutoCompleteByCode(input).ToList();
                    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, result, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), TimeSpan.Zero);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Matter> GetMattersByMatterCodeSearch(string input)
    {
        return _matterData.GetMattersByMatterCodeSearch(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what's calling your `MatterController` constructor? Presumably you've got an IoC container fixing up all your dependencies somewhere, but you haven't told us anything about that...

Comment: I am calling the matter controller via an AJAX call from my jquery. 
This is an application that I have inherited, so I am not really sure if there's an IoC container built. 
The only other thing I skipped out, which in hind sight might be useful is that the application is using Ninject and it is registering the interface, I am going to add the code to my main question

Comment: given that Ninject is an DI system who's job it is to inject the right implementation of an interface into your controller, I think you've answered your own question...

Comment: "the application is using Ninject" - well there we go. That's the IoC container...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rason why your code is using the right implementation of `IMatterDAL` is because it's being passed as a parameter in the constructor of `MatterController`. I'm almost sure that your code is using some [Dependency Injection framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to resolve `IMatterDAL`.

In fact Ninject is a DI Framework. Your code should have something like

`kernel.Bind<IMatterDAL>().To<MatterDAL >();`

Comment: It seems your are right, after I did further I see a ninject implementation which is resolving IMatterDAL.

Thanks a lot!